# Should I do AutoCAD first or 3D Max?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

I want to go for industrial design. Learning computer aided design and rendering is the main aim of learning these softwares. Should I do AutoCAD first or 3D max ?

Comment: I've never understood the either/or question. Can't you learn both in tandem? That's how I learned most the software I know.

Comment: in any case you shouldnt learn either

Answer (score 2):

Between those two choices its a bit of a toss up. Neither one is used too heavily in industrial design. What you should probably be looking at is SolidWorks instead. If you're only choices are 3DMax and AutoCAD, I'd go with AutoCAD.

A great website for everything industrial design is [Core77](http://www.core77.com/)

Comment: I agree as far as no autocad or max im slighly opposed to solidworks, it might be one of the softwares you would use but i suspect not. Anyway aurocad used to be the go to guy 15-20 years ago. In either case a industrial desigber probably needs to start from the basics as youd need to be able ti switch between 5-20 apps. Where max and autocad come at the very last good to know level.